# local animations in Objective-C

Tags: ios, animation

I've been looking through a few applications for inspiration and see many image based animations, for logos or text etc. However, some of these animations don't appear to be possible in objective-c or at least from my knowledge. So I've been looking to get my own created. However, I've read that you cannot run .swf in objective-c. So, what are my options for animation files that I can run? If I go to a freelancer and request an animation. What type of animation do I need to be asking for?

This could be for a simple logo animation on the application launch, or could be for an event in the game. I.e, a cutscene.

**Question**

What animation files would best suit my needs and/or is it possible to run it locally? I don't want to be including html. A simple file, launched create the animation. Like a .gif.

Comment: The launch image can't have any animation - it is a static image or storyboard scene.  In your app you can use a series of images, programmatic animation of elements or even a movie file

Comment: @Paulw11 I've seen a few examples of an animated launch screen, one featured app "O K A Y ?" is a good example.

Comment: What they probably did is substituted an animated view that looked the same as their static launch screen once the app was launched.  The actual launch image cannot be animated.  The purpose of the launch image is to give the impression that app is already active while it is still launching and so it should look like the initial view of your app.  According to the Apple guidelines it shouldn't be used for "splash" screens but this is widely ignored and Apple doesn't reject apps for violating this.

Comment: I donwloaded that app and if you watch carefully when it launches it has a static image of 3 grey dots in the middle of the screen then the logo animates.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah, I see what you're saying. However, I think we're on different tracks. I mean, how can I achieve that. And the answer to that is a stack of images then iterate through them to give the impression of animation?

Comment: Yes, you can animate a series of images in a `UIImageView`, you can play an mpeg movie, you could use Core Animation, Sprite Kit,  OpenGL or Metal (probably not these last three as they are a bit "heavy" for a splash screen)